# There are infinitely many prime which have arbitrary large gap in their digits in particular base expansion

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, digits

Consider $m$ and $r$ is any fixed positive integer and $t$ is a variable $(t=0,1,2,3,...)$. Below, $[a]$ denotes the greatest integer function of $a$ (or floor function).

**Claim 1 :**  There exists a pair $m,r$ with $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2} $ and $0\le r<m$ such that integer $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ is prime for infinitely many positive integer $t$.

*Edit:* Weak Claim: let $S=\left\{\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right] : m,t,r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \text{ and } 0\le r< m \text{ and } m\ge 2\right\}$, then $S$ contains infinitely many primes.

**Question**: How to prove claim 1 or Weak Claim?

---

Motivation: If Claim 1 is true then we can say there exist arbitrary large gaps between digits of prime $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ in base expansion $mt+r$, because we can express $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ as a polynomial in terms of $mt+r$ as $$\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(x_it+y_i)(mt+r)^i$$ for some non negative integer $x_i,y_i$ such that $0\le x_it+y_i<mt+r$ then there exists a positive integer $N$  such that $x_it+y_i$  are digits for $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ in base expansion $mt+r$ for all $t\ge N$. *such representation [link2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362137/149083) exist*.

Here $x_i\equiv r^{m-1-i}\pmod{m}$ for $i=0,1,...m-1$ and $y_i=\left[\frac{x_ir}{m}\right]$ this implies $x_i+y_i\le m+r-2$

This follows below theorem

**Theorem:** For all $m,r$, integer $\left[\frac{(mt+r)^m}{m}\right]$ do not have a digit $x_it+y_i$ such that $x_i+y_i=m+r-1$ in their base system $mt+r$ for all $t\ge N$ for some  positive integer $N$.

---

**Example**: Consider $m=3$ and $r=2$, following table shows for $t$ which gives $\left[\frac{(3t+2)^3}{3}\right]$ is prime and we can write $\left[\frac{(3t+2)^3}{3}\right]=(t)(3t+2)^2+(2t+1)(3t+2)+(t)(3t+2)^0$ such digits representation follows our assumption for all $t\ge 1$. following table also suggest there are infinitely many primes exist.

| t | $\left[\frac{(3t+2)^3}{3}\right]$ is prime | $\left[\frac{(3t+2)^3}{3}\right]$ in base $3t+2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | $(1, 0)_2$ |
| 1 | 41 | $(1, 3, 1)_5$ |
| 3 | 443 | $(3, 7, 3)_{11}$ |
| 5 | 1637 | $(5, 11, 5)_{17}$ |
| 13 | 22973 | $(13, 27, 13)_{41}$ |
| 15 | 34607 | $(15, 31, 15)_{47}$ |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |

let $f(n)=\#\left\{t\le n:\left[\frac{(3t+2)^3}{3}\right] \text{is prime}\right\}$ and $\pi(n)$ shows prime counting function.

| $n$ | $f(n)$ | $\pi(n)$ | $2f(n)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $10$ | 4 | 4 | 8 |
| $10^2$ | 12 | 25 | 24 |
| $10^3$ | 108 | 168 | 216 |
| $10^4$ | 763 | 1229 | 1526 |
| $2\times 10^4$ | 1412 | 2262 | 2824 |

The above table suggest, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2f(n)}{\pi(n)}>1$

Please suggest, which method is useful here to prove above observation.

*Motivation: Professor James Maynard proved, Let $a_0 ∈ \{0,..., 9\}$ then there are infinitely many prime numbers which do not have the digit $a_0$ in their decimal expansion.*
Maybe the above claim is somewhere related to this. Welcome to all your suggestions, comments, edits and solutions. Thanks.

My related observations and questions links,

1. $x_i\equiv r^{m-1-i}\pmod{m}$ for $i=0,1,...,m-1$ MSE [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852897/647719)
2. Above such representation exist, [link2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362137/149083)